Как получить права для токена для работы с VK_API?
Пишется бот, который подключается к аккаунту ВК и от лица человека chat-gpt общается с ним.
Проблема возникает в том, что токен, который получается по этой ссылке
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=ВАШ_APP_ID&display=page&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=messages,offline&response_type=token&v=5.131
и в дальнейшем вставляется в код выдает такую ошибку
Ошибка VK API: Access denied: no access to call this method
Везде пишут, что эта ошибка связана с недостатком прав пользователя, но нигде не указано, каких именно прав. В самом VK_dev нет никаких настроек приложения, которые могли бы давать эти права. Через офф.документацию VK есть предположение, что, возможно, права будут, если подтвердить аккаунт через паспортные данные(серая галочка).
Касательно Standalone-приложения: Vk это поменяли и теперь на выбор есть только другие категории(прил.1)

Если же брать другой Vk-dev от них же, то и там на выбор совершенно другие категории(прил.2)

Кто с таким сталкивался? Буду рад Вашим ответам.
Заранее спасибо за ответ!
P.S.:GPT задалбывал, но никакого толкового ответа на этот счёт он мне не дал.
